# Consulta com Eloquent do Laravel

Tags: query, laravel-5

Tenho esta consulta:

```
select 
Q.id,Q.questao, 
D.disciplina, 
S.serie, 
S.ensino 
from questoes as Q 
left join capitulos_questoes as CQ 
on CQ.questoes_id = Q.id 
left join modulos_questoes as MQ 
on MQ.questoes_id = Q.id 
left join banco_disciplinas as D 
on (D.id = CQ.banco_disciplinas_id) or (D.id = MQ.banco_disciplinas_id) 
left join banco_series as S 
on (S.id = CQ.banco_series_id) or (S.id = MQ.banco_series_id)
```

Preciso paginar os resultados desta consulta no Laravel 5.2. Estou com dificuldades em fazer a consulta com o Eloquent por estar usando o `or` no `LEFT JOIN`.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
$questoes=\DB::select('select Q.id,Q.questao, D.disciplina, S.serie, S.ensino
            from questoes as Q 
            left join capitulos_questoes as CQ
            on CQ.questoes_id = Q.id
            left join modulos_questoes as MQ 
            on MQ.questoes_id = Q.id
            LEFT join banco_disciplinas as D 
            on (D.id = CQ.banco_disciplinas_id) or (D.id = MQ.banco_disciplinas_id)
            left join banco_series as S 
            on (S.id = CQ.banco_series_id) or (S.id = MQ.banco_series_id)')
            ->paginate(15);
```

mas retorna um erro dizendo que não é possível paginar um array. Como posso resolver?

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar o eloquent ORM para simplificar seu código. Você está utilizando o query build. Vai facilitar sua vida.

Comment: @MiguelBatista, esta é minha dúvida, como passar essa consulta para o eloquent ORM

Comment: a sua sintaxe que estava errado é `$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);` e ai por diante poderia montar a sua `query builder` normalmente. Só quero deixar claro que a minha intenção é deixar o usuário ciente dos erros como forma de ajudar ! exemplo link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu não me engano, quando se usa o `DB` tem que fazer a Paginação manualmente.

Mas se quiser usar o Eloquent pode fazer assim:

```
$questoes = Questao::leftJoin('capitulos_questoes', 'capitulos_questoes.questoes_id', '=', 'questoes.id')
->leftJoin('modulos_questoes', 'modulos_questoes.questoes_id', '=', 'questoes.id')
->leftJoin('banco_disciplinas', function($join){
      $join->on('banco_disciplinas.id', '=', 'capitulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id')
      ->orOn('banco_disciplinas.id', '=', 'modulos_questoes.banco_disciplinas_id');
})
->leftJoin('banco_series', function($join){
      $join->on('banco_series.id', '=', 'capitulos_questoes.banco_series_id')
      ->orOn('banco_series.id', '=', 'modulos_questoes.banco_series_id');
})
->paginate(15);
```

Aonde está escrito `Questao::` é um Model que precisará ser criado.

Se estiver usando o composer é só entrar na Pasta do projeto pelo Prompt e digitar:

```
php artisan make:model Questao
```

Mas como o nome da tabela é em português e no plural você terá que renomear ela na class do Model criado.

Então o Model estará assim:

```
class Questao extends Model{

   protected $table = "questoes";

}
```

Obrigatoriamente terá que criar essa variável acima na classe para identificar a tabela correta.

Comment: Tentei fazer paginação manual e também não funcionou. Este código que me passou dá erro de sintaxe nos primeiros `on` dentro de `function($join)`

Comment: Arrumei o código.

Comment: Parou de dar erro de sintaxe mas agora não reconhece o nome das tabelas, apesar de estar escrito corretamente. Vou seguir essa linha de raciocínio sua pra tentar resolver, muito obrigada

Comment: Então, Amanda. Está vendo onde está escrito **Questao::** ? Vou te explicar...

Comment: `Questao` é justamente o nome do meu Model  para a tabela `questoes` , está certinho. Só não está reconhecendo a tabela `banco_disciplinas`

Comment: Ah entendi. Editei antes de você falar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46593/discussion-between-gumball-and-amanda-lima).

Answer (score 0):

Amanda você pode fazer a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
$questoes = Questao::with(['capitulosQuestoes',
                           'bancoDisciplinas','
                           'bancoSeries'])
            ->paginate(15);
```

no html você exibe `{{$questoes->links()}}`

Para fazer isso você precisa criar no model Questao os métodos que serão responsáveis pelos relacionamentos de 1 para n, n para n e etc.

Ex. se a relacao de questões e capitulos é 1 para n o metodo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public function capitulosQuestoes(){
    return $this->hasMany(CapituloQuestao::class,'questao_id');
}
```

`CapituloQuestao::class` é o módel referente a tabela capitulos_questoes e o campo `'questao_id'` seria a chave estrangeira que faz relacionamento com a tabela questoes.

se quiser saber mais sobre relacionamento entre models você pode verificar [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).